How to save a parent entity with a list of child entities on Spring Boot?
I'm working on a project that has a OneToMany relationship between two entities: Exam and ExamInputs.
When saving an Exam, I'm passing a list of ExamInputs on the payload, in order to save them at the same time.
I didn't want to save the exam first, and then the ExamInputs, as I believe it's possible to save them all at the same time.
The problem is that when I make the request, the ExamInputs are saved with EXAM_ID as null, since the parent is being created at the same time and I don't set it on ExamInput object.
ExamEntity
@Entity
public class ExamEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "Long")
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String examType;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "exam")
    private List<ExamInputEntity> examInputs;

ExamInputEntity
@Entity
public class ExamInputEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String inputName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String inputValue;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "exam_id")
    private ExamEntity exam;

Payload
{
  "examType":"Test"
  "examInputs": [
    {
      "inputName": "test",
      "inputValue": "test",
    }
  ]
}

Is it possible to save ExamInputs without appending the parent object to it? For now, I'm calling examInput.setExam(exam) to force it to work.
I've tried using different cascade types, but I'm learning and I'm not sure which one is the best for each case.

It is a bidirectional relationship. There is no other way then setting the reference to the parent object in each child object programatically. After doing it you can save the parent object with attached children in one go.

The ExamInputEntity -> ExamEntity association cannot be done automatically you have to manually take care of it, usually like this:
public void setExamInputs(List<ExamInputEntity> examInputs) {
    // null checks etc..
    for (ExamInputEntity examInput : examInputs) {
        examImput.setExam(this);
    }
    this.examInputs = examInputs;
}

And you should do the same if you have for example an: addExamInput(ExamInputEntity examInput) and so on.
After that because of Cascade.ALL when you save the examEntity all its children will be saved as well.
